# How to detect slash key using KeyDown event?

Tags: c#, wpf

I can't find slash key in `Windows.System.Input.Key` enumeration.
Yes, I know, it's OEM key, but there is a key which produces slash on every keyboard, how can I detect it with any kind of `KeyDown` event?

Comment: Now, do you mean hyphen (-), or if you do mean slash, then which one? Forward (/) or backward (\)?

Comment: "/" - this is commonly called "slash", "\" this is commonly called "backslash". It's interesting how to detect any of similar OEM keys.

Comment: This is a simple, very precise question. It requires some ill will to misunderstand it. In original question I also had WPF in title, to make it more precise, because WinForms uses a slightly different enumeration and keyboard events. So fight the user all you want, but you are far from being helpful. BTW, here's the good answer in comment limit: "OEM keys can map to different symbols on various keyboards, so instead of using key code use Text property of text element instead, because the system have already mapped the OEM key to character.". I'm just saying.

Comment: @Harry lmao "It requires some ill will to misunderstand". It blows my mind how there is always at least one uber tool on almost every single question that does just this. I wish I could +1000 this. Then of course after you provide clarification they still don't help, which implies that was never their intent in the first place...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't.

Use the `TextInput` event and simply test for `e.Text == "/"`.

(You may need to use `PreviewTextInput` for some controls that handle the bubbling event.)

Comment: The RichTextBox does not have either of these events. How do I capture a forward slash key press reliably?

Comment: I don't know, nor can i research this right now, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I get OemQuestion and Oem5 (with no modifiers) for the two slashes on my system. You get something different?

Comment: No, I get `Oem5` for backslash, and `OemQuestion` for forward slash, but I'm not sure if it would work on all keyboards. It's important that it would always be a key used to produce "/" character, because it's used to trigger events on text input.